# Deny the location permission and later grant the location for xamarin iOS 8 application return always false

Tags: ios, gps, xamarin, location

I am working in a iOS/xamarin app. (iOS 8).
I was using this tutorial to know the user location:
http://www.themethodology.net/2014/10/getting-permission-to-access-user.html

And the follow codes works to know if the uses has the location services enabled and if the applications is authorized to use the location.

```
CLLocationManager clm = new CLLocationManager ();

public bool LocationServicesEnabled {
            get {return CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled;}
        }
        public bool IsAuthorized {
            get {return CLAuthorizationStatus.Authorized == _authstatusLast;}
        }
```

But, if the user select the first time: Don't allow, after that, he changes the permission in:

```
Privacy >> Location >> MyApp >> ON
```

The `IsAuthorized` method is always false.
Someone has an idea about how solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to know if the application has permission to use the location services (Not if the service is enabled).

```
public bool IsAuthorized {
            get {return CLLocationManager.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse ;}
        }
```

You can use `CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse` when the app is using `AuthorizeWhenIsInUser` and if you are using `AuthorizedAlways` you need change that in the `CLAutorizationStatus`. 
Also, is necessary for iOS 8 modify the keys in your `plist` file:
More information about the plist here.
http://www.themethodology.net/2014/10/getting-permission-to-access-user.html